# How to get data from Voicebase with Twilio on PHP

Tags: php, twilio

I am currently trying to use Voicebase's Add-on for Twilio using the  feature. From PHP, how can I be able to access the data collected from Voicebase?

I understand that Voicebase uses a Callback URL, but I am trying to collect the data from the action part of **`<Record action='url/for/processing'></Record>`**.

I've tried to get the payload data from cURL and file_get_contents, both not returning data in the payload section of **api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSid/Recordings/RecordingSid/AddOnResults/.json**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are using one of the Voicebase transcription add-ons. When you install the add-on in your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/product/voice) you set a callback URL for the add-on there.

You need to enter a callback URL on the Add-on configuration page after you have installed it. Then, as the [add-on documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/add-ons/using-add-ons) says, your callback will be invoked automatically for each recording your account makes.

[image: Find the callback request method field on the add on form and enter your callback URL there.]

The callback will only be invoked once the data is ready, transcription can take time and is dependent on the length of the audio to transcribe. The transcription may not be ready when the `action` attribute of your [`<Record>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) is called. You need to wait for the add-on callback itself to be called.

If you are looking for instant results using recording and transcription in order to create a real time voice powered call, you'll want to check out using the `speech` input type for [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) instead.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I used the callback before this, and I did receive data, but I want to continue the call after the recording is done and repeat to verify the speech. Is there a way to connect the callback url to the action url.

Comment: These callbacks are asynchronous to the call as they might take some time. If you are only making short recordings and you want to affect the call with them, then you would need to keep the call going after the recording is made (with a looping pause or message, perhaps?) and then when you receive the callback with the recording/transcription [update the call using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state), redirecting it to some TwiML that plays back the recording or reads the transcription.